# Failed to connect to bus: Host is down

Tags: centos, systemctl, termux

There is an error when I use command 'systemctl' in centos in Termux.

[The error goes like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkHjA.jpg)

By the way, Termux is an Android terminal emulator and Linux environment app that works directly with no rooting or setup required.